# R list of vectors to sparse matrix

Tags: r, list, dataframe, sparse-matrix

I have a data frame containing a columns/list of vectors - each cell in this column contains varying length vector of | separated number.

```
> dput(test)
structure(list(classes = c("30136|10263|10304|10207|10148|10319|10109|10306|10281|10187|10181|10046|10255|10018", 
"10271|10306|10019|10073|10319|10112|10156|10069|10218|10011|10175|10039|10015|10304", 
"10191|10286|10257", "10178|10325", "10156|10304|10294|10009", 
"10124|10271|10306|10019|10319|10112|10156|10011|10039|10304|10272|10250|10109|10150|10163"
), fullurl = c("www.lonny.com/Gigi%20Hadid's%20Parents%20Are%20Selling%20Their%20Malibu%20Mansion?utm_campaign=Yaho-LN-US-Desktop-Specials-Gigi-Hadids-Parents-Are-Selli&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=yaho", 
"www.msn.com/?ocid=UE01DHP&pc=EUPP_UE01", "www.mybodygallery.com/photos-2576-body-shape.htm", 
"news.abs-cbn.com/entertainment", "runt-of-the-web.com/savage-reddit-roasts", 
"www.msn.com/en-us?cobrand=hp13.msn.com&ocid=HPCDHP&pc=HPDTDFJS"
)), .Names = c("classes", "fullurl"), row.names = c(17L, 40L, 
49L, 50L, 52L, 60L), class = "data.frame")
```

I need to convert this into a sparse matrix or a "stretched" data frame,
such that for each possible class in data - a dedicated column will be present containing 0/1 depending if this class assigned to this url.
Any suggestions appreciated.
I thought using

```
do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(test$classes), "|", fixed=T))
```

but that didn't do the job.

Comment: CAn you show expected output based on this input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try

```
library(qdapTools)
 d1 <- mtabulate(setNames(strsplit(as.character(test$classes), "|", 
               fixed=T), test$fullurl))
```

Comment: great! although I get a warning : Warning message:
In data.row.names(row.names, rowsi, i) :
  some row.names duplicated: 17,19,40  and in the result I do not see row names (url paths).

Answer (score 0):

```
classes <- unique(unlist(strsplit(test$classes, "|", fixed = TRUE)))
sapply(classes, grepl, test$classes) * 1
```